# How to post a picture to a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, post, sdk, facebook-group

I'm trying to post a picture to a group. It isn't a problem to post a message with an link and no problem with an extern image. But i can't post an "intern" (facebook picture) to a group. I get the error "(#100) FBCDN image is not allowed in stream: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid={picture-id}"

is there any possibility to post a photo to a group or post an uploaded-facebook-picture?

Comment: Do you have the picture id? Or you want to upload the image to facebook and then post it?

Comment: yes i have the picture id. but this doesn't help. or do you know more?

Comment: I think the issue is related to permissions. Your facebook session might not have the proper permission to read that photo. Can you post some code on how you are opening the session and posting to the group?

Answer (score 8):

You can't post images to Facebook which are hosted on Facebook's own CDN, you need to upload it from your own server.

The source for this is that when you try to do so, you receive an error message telling you that you can't use an FBCDN image; fbcdn is part of the URL of Facebook's CDN.

The workaround is to attach an image which is hosted on your own / another server

Comment: thanks for your replay. sad becouse via the website this is possible... but thats life and perhaps facebook will change it in the future... thanks. <3